# J-measurable sets and functions of class $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

If $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $C^1$ class and $det f^{\prime}(0)=0$ show that, when $r\rightarrow 0$
$$\dfrac{Vol(f(B[0,r]))}{ Vol(B[0,r])} \rightarrow 0$$

where $Vol(X)$ is n-dimensional volume to set $J$-measurable $X$.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks

Comment: honestly, I do not understand what is your problem. Try to rreformulate it, may be someone could help you

Comment: okay, I'll leave the specific problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant of the Jacobian (what the OP denotes by $f'$) is precisely the coefficient by which an infinitesimal element of volume is modified when $f$ is applied to it. Since the Jacobian is assumed to be zero at the point, it is going to be smaller than $\epsilon>0$ in a suitable neighborhood for any $\epsilon$, by the $C^1$ assumption on $f$. Then the volume of the image will be at most $\epsilon$ times the volume of the original ball, i.e. the ratio $\dfrac{Vol(f(B[0,r]))}{ Vol(B[0,r])}$ is bounded above by $\epsilon$.

Comment: thanks for answering. known to $ Vol(f^{\prime} (0)(B[0,r]))=|det f^{\prime}(0)|Vol(B[0,r])$ then $Vol(f^{\prime}(0) (B[0,r]))=0$, but this is as it relates to $Vol(f(B[0,r]))$ ?

Comment: Your formula $Vol(f^{\prime} (0)(B[0,r]))=|det f^{\prime}(0)|Vol(B[0,r])$ is incorrect in general, and I am not sure it is meaningful.  If the determinant of the Jacobian is constant on the $r$-ball, then one could possibly make sense of the formula, but in general it's problematic. Think of the ball as being made up of infinitesimal volume elements; by applying the Jacobian matrix at each such volume element, we get the corresponding volume element in the image. Summing over this subdivision, we get the total volume of the image.

Comment: @helmonio, In more standard language, you would write the volume of $f(B)$ as an integral over $B$ with a Jacobian factor, as in $vol(f(B))=\int_B J_f\; dvol$, where $J_f$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix.  If this is bounded by $\epsilon$ then we get an upper bound for the volume of $f(B)$ in terms of $\epsilon\; vol(B)$.

Comment: As can be justified in this case $ f (B [0, r]) $ is measurable jordan?

Comment: I should add that the equality in my previous comment will hold only if $f$ is injective, but in any case the upper bound for the volume in terms of the integral above will hold generally.

Comment: For example, if $f$  is the map $z↦z^2$ on the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$, you will have only an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By the change of variable formula you have
$$ \int_{f(B(0,r))}1 dx = \int_{B(0,r)} 1 \cdot \text{Jac }f(x) dx $$

Since the Jacobian of $f$ at zero is zero and $f$ is $C^1$ it follows that for $\varepsilon >0$ given, there exists $r_\varepsilon >0$ such that for any $r <r_0$ we have $|\text {Jac} f(x)| <\varepsilon$ on $B(0,r)$. From the above inequality we get

$$ | f(B(0,r))| \leq |B(0,r)| \cdot \varepsilon,\ \forall r<r_\varepsilon.$$

This expresses the fact that $\frac{|f(B(0,r))|}{|B(0,r)|}$ goes to $0$ as $r \to 0$.

Comment: greetings, to use the change of variables theorem $f$ should be injective in a neighborhood of the origin? I am using the spivak michael (calculation in varieties)

Comment: As can be justified in this case $ f (B [0, r]) $ is measurable jordan?

Comment: @helmonio: you are right. It is necessary for $f$ to be injective.

Comment: I would appreciate a counterexample.